# Chromeのデベロッパーツールで任意の操作を行いたい。

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

### やりたいこと

Chromeのデベロッパーツールで指定のdivタグ以下の全てのaタグを別タブとして表示させたいです。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

下の画像の赤枠内の全てのリンクを別タブで開くようなイメージです。

[image: イメージ画像]

Answer (score 1):

chromeのコンソールでこれを実行すると全てのリンクが開けました。

```
let d = document.querySelectorAll('#ToolList a');// #ToolListはYahoo!独自のID
d.forEach(function(link){
  open(link.href);
});
```

ただし、ポップアップを全て許可する必要があります。許可しなかった場合は1つのタブしか開くことができません。